# Sending receipts - PHP library for V2 API

Tags: square-connect, receipt

I use the square-connect v2 PHP library to process credit card transactions from our website. Transactions are processed (appear in our account and the customer's statement), but no receipt is sent to the card-holder. I submit the customer email address with the transaction, and in my test cases Square already has an email address on file for the card. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Square's e-commerce API does not automatically send receipts like checking out with Square with an in-person payment. I'd suggest sending your own receipt to your customers.

Comment: OK. I was wondering if I had left something out. We do send our own order confirmation as well. If the API developers take requests, this is an enhancement that I and our customers would find useful.